# Nodejs - What is the order of execution in this code? Async await inside for of loop

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, async-await

Let say we have a model "user", and a model "game".

One user can have many games, but one game belongs to one user only.

In "user" model, we have field "gamesCount" - the total of game that user has

In "games" model, we have field userId - related to user

Now we need to loop through all users, and for each user, we query the "game" collection to get how many games that user has, then save the value "gamesCount" to user model.

I have 2 snippets of code:

```
updateUserGamesCount: async function (req, res) {
    try {
        let users = await User.find({});
        for (let user of users) {
            user.gamesCount= await Game.count({userId: user._id});
            await user.save();
        }
        return res.status(200).send("Success");
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    }
}
```

This 1st snippet doesn't work. It just load for a while and then request time out. When I tried to modify gamesCount value to see if it's updated or not, then the value is not updated after this 1st snippet run.

```
updateUserGamesCount: async function (req, res) {
    try {
        let users = await User.find({});
        for (let user of users) {
            user.gamesCount= await Game.count({userId: user._id});
            user.save();
        }
        return res.status(200).send("Success");
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    }
}
```

This 2nd snippet works. The only difference is in 2nd snippet, I remove the await before user.save();

Why does this happen? I thought that user.save() is asynchronous and we need to use await? And what exactly is the order of execution in these line of code?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does `User.save` return a promise?

Comment: @StephenCleary: I updated my question. It just load for a while and then request time out. When I tried to modify gamesCount value to see if it's updated or not, the value is not updated after this 1st snippet run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q:** Why did the first code snippet work and not the other?

**A:** I think we need to be clear on the **definition** of 'it works'. It worked because no error was thrown?

I suspect your 2nd code snippet did not work at all instead you're just masking the error by removing the `await` keyword.

The first example work because you're waiting for the `save` operation to finish before moving on and if an `exception` is thrown then it is caught by the `try` block. Whereas the 2nd code no longer waits for the `save()` response to return and simply returned `success`.

If this theory holds true then nothing should have `saved` successfully. Whether it worked or not, only the database can tell the truth. The 1st code snippet is the correct approach, but it can be done better performance wise.

Consider bundling up all the `save` promises and do a `promise.all(...)` for *possible* performance gain. Alternatively doing a one `save` operation which include all the modification can be a good option in certain use cases as well.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Thank you @Samuel Toh. Actually I said that 2nd snippet works because when I check the database all values of gamesCount are correct. I'm not sure how is that

Comment: Assuming you have a `clean` database for each run. When you ran the first code nothing gets populated at all? or was it some? If it is the latter then maybe it could possibly be an intermittent probem.

Comment: No I tried to modify value of some records to wrong values. Then I run the 2nd snippet. When I checked those values again, they are correct. That's why I have to raise this question, because it doesn't make sense with what I learned about Promise or async/await

Comment: I think it is better to rollback the database to a clean state before attempting each try. I think you may have made a mistake somewhere while comparing.